# How to convert chating conversation to image and save in sd card

Tags: android, bitmap, chat

[image: Chating conversation]

I working for chating application, in that i need to convert the complete conversation to an image and saved that image into sd card. I displayed the conversation as a listview.
i am using the below code :

```
        lstSms.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        lstSms.destroyDrawingCache();
        lstSms.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = getTransparentBitmapCopy(lstSms.getDrawingCache());


private Bitmap getTransparentBitmapCopy(Bitmap source)
{
    int width =  source.getWidth();
    int height = source.getHeight();
    Bitmap copy = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    source.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    copy.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return copy;
}
```

But i am not getting the bitmap. so, please guide me how to implement this.

Comment: Please explain what "not getting the bitmap" means.

Comment: why do you copy the bitmap ?

Comment: i dont know exactly, whether it is correct or not. i just googled and used the above code. @CommonsWare

Comment: Without creating the bitmap then how to set actual content in to that bitmap...thats the part written in getTransparentBitmapCopy()@njzk2